# Short story about some sort of test or game, with an awkward video call

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I recall a novella or short story about a man who has been putting off some sort of test or evaluation.  The scene that sticks in my mind is an early video call with the person who signs the protagonist up for the test, who complains about the camera on the video call being misaligned. The narrator reveals to the reader that this was on purpose to annoy callers.

I don't recall the nature of the test, nor the outcome, but this scene has stuck with me.  I may have read it in a copy of *Analog* or *Asimov's* magazine, around the mid 90's.

Comment: This sounds familiar, and I thought you were describing a scene from Judith Merril's *The Tomorrow People*, but I couldn't actually find it in there.